# index.js:4 NotSupportedError: MediaStreamError found in simple peer

Tags: javascript, node.js, webrtc, peerjs, simple-peer

I used simple peer js for peer to peer connection in node JS. But Iam getting this error

> index.js:4 NotSupportedError: MediaStreamError

here is my code

index.js

```js
var getUserMedia = require('getusermedia')

getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: false }, function (err, stream) {
  if (err) return console.error(err)

  var Peer = require('simple-peer')
  var peer = new Peer({
    initiator: location.hash === '#init',
    trickle: false,
    stream: stream
  })

  peer.on('signal', function (data) {
    document.getElementById('yourId').value = JSON.stringify(data)
  })

  document.getElementById('connect').addEventListener('click', function () {
    var otherId = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('otherId').value)
    peer.signal(otherId)
  })

  document.getElementById('send').addEventListener('click', function () {
    var yourMessage = document.getElementById('yourMessage').value
    peer.send(yourMessage)
  })

  peer.on('data', function (data) {
    document.getElementById('messages').textContent += data + '\n'
  })

  peer.on('stream', function (stream) {
    var video = document.createElement('video');
    document.body.appendChild(video);

    // video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
    // video.play();

    video.srcObject=stream;
video.play();
  })
})
```

Comment: Do you want to get this code on a web page? if so how did you deploy it? (browserify?)  Is a javascript solution also good for your application?

Comment: I'm getting this issue myself, same setup.  It may be getusermedia npm module, as I'm using that as well.  Did you find an answer?

Comment: I think this answers your question: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63266258/webrtc-error-while-creating-video-chat-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63266258/webrtc-error-while-creating-video-chat-app)