# WebRTC error while creating video chat app

Tags: javascript, webrtc, p2p, simplewebrtc, openwebrtc

I am getting this error on console while refreshing the page.. Everythng else works fine the Chats and everthing.. just the streaming part is not working

```
NotSupportedError: MediaStreamError
    at module.exports (http://192.168.1.10:9966/index.js:3081:17)
    at Object.1.getusermedia (http://192.168.1.10:9966/index.js:4:1)
    at o (http://192.168.1.10:9966/index.js:1:265)
    at r (http://192.168.1.10:9966/index.js:1:431)
    at http://192.168.1.10:9966/index.js:1:460
```

while creating a video chat app

This is my index.js

```
var getUserMedia = require('getusermedia')

getUserMedia({video: true, audio: false}, function (err, stream) {
    var Peer = require('simple-peer')
    var peer = new Peer({
        initiator: location.hash === '#init',
        trickle: false,
        stream: stream
    })

    peer.on('signal', function (data) {
        document.getElementById('yourId').value = JSON.stringify(data)
    })

    document.getElementById('connect').addEventListener('click', function () {
        var otherId = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('otherId').value)
        peer.signal(otherId)
    })

    document.getElementById('send').addEventListener('click', function () {
        var yourMessage = document.getElementById('yourMessage').value
        peer.send(yourMessage)
    })

    peer.on('data', function (data) {
        document.getElementById('messages').textContent += data + '\n'
    })

    peer.on('stream', function (stream) {
        var video = document.createElement('video')
        document.body.appendChild(video)

        video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream)
        video.play()
    })
})
```

This is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>CHatting Video</title>
</head>
<body>

<label>Your ID:</label><br/>
<textarea id="yourId"></textarea><br/>
<label>Other ID:</label><br/>
<textarea id="otherId"></textarea>
<button id="connect">connect</button>
<br/>

<label>Enter Message:</label><br/>
<textarea id="yourMessage"></textarea>
<button id="send">send</button>
<pre id="messages"></pre>

<script src="index.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I send a message to other browser it works fine but for video chat it does not work
Any Idea on how to fix this.????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the error..
I was using `getUserMedia` instead of `navigator.getUserMedia`

getUserMedia has been deprecated.